# Sum of norms over elements is not equal to norm over the whole $\Omega$

Tags: numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method, interpolation-theory

In my finite element notes, after the proof of the global estimate for the interpolation error, assuming a regular triangulation with triangles $T_m$:

$$\sum_m|v - \Pi_h^r v|_{s,p,T_m} \leq \sigma^{-s} h^{k+1-s}|u|_{k+1,\Omega}$$ for $u \in W^{k+1,p}(\Omega)$

After that, the professor told that in general $$\sum_m |v - \Pi_h^r v|_{k,p,T_m}^p \ne |v - \Pi_h^r v|_{k,p,\Omega}^p$$ **I'm trying to find an example of this** All I know is that, for instance, the space $X_h =\{ v \in C^o (\Omega): v_{|T_m} \in P^1(T_m) \}$ is not a subspace of $H^2(\Omega)$ since the second derivative has delta distributions.

I'd like to find even 1D example for which the sum over the intervals of the norms is not equal to the norm on the whole space, but I can't come up with anything.

Comment: What is $\Pi_h^r v$? Could you define a regular triangulation of $\Omega$? I'm guessing the $|\cdot |_{k,p,T_m}$ is the $L^p(T_m)$-norm of the $k$-th derivatives?

Comment: A regular triangulation satisfies some properties on the diameter of the triangles. But it's just a detail, it's not relevant.  While $\Pi_h^r v$ is the interpolation operator, that maps a continuous function in the polynomial space $P^r(\Omega)$ of degree $r$

Comment: I would expect $\sum_m |v- \Pi v|_{k,p,T}^p = |v-\Pi v|_{k,p,\Omega}^p$ to hold, but this is hard to judge. We need more information how $\Pi$ is determined, and whether these two $\Pi$ operators in the inequality are actually the same operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem really is $v - \Pi_h^r v \not\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

To give an example, consider $\Omega = (-1,1)$ with the triangulation $T_0 = (-1,0)$, $T_2 = (0,1)$. Then, the function $w$ defined via $w(x) = |x|$ belongs to a $P^1$ space and $w \not\in H^2(\Omega)$. In particular,
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^2 | w |_{2,2,T_i}^2 = 0 \ne \infty = | w |_{2,2,\Omega}^2.
$$

Comment: I just edited my post, there was a small but relevant typo in the exponents. Basically, what my professor said is that in order to have that equality we need higher order continuity across interelement boundaries. It seems to me like you provided an example where we have non enough differentiability so that the equality doesn't hold anymore, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you have enough regularity (i.e., $y := v - \Pi_h^r v \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$), then $(D^\alpha y)_{T_i} = D^\alpha (y_{T_i})$ for multiindices with $|\alpha| \le k$ and then the norms are identical.

Comment: Before accepting your answer, let me ask one last thing: why does $|w|_{2,2,\Omega} = \infty$? You have $\int_{\Omega=(-1,1)} \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} dx$. Now, $\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} = \delta_{0}(x)$. Why is that integral $\infty$?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit sloppy by writing that the norm is $\infty$. In the sense of functions, $w''$ is not defined, i.e., $|w|_{2,2,\Omega}$ is not defined. If you interpret $w'' = \delta_0$ (in the sense of distributions), then $|w|_{2,2,\Omega}^2 = \int_{-1}^1 \delta_0^2 \mathrm dx$ (note the square!). If we try to define this integral, the only sensible value would be $\infty$.

Comment: No worries, I just don't have a good background on distributions! Why the only sensible value is $\infty$? Could you point me to a source for this kind of things?

Comment: No, sorry, I do not have a reference.

Comment: Thanks anyway. But what di you mean when you say "the only sensible value would be $\infty$"?

Comment: A very informal argument would be the following: $\delta_0$ is $+\infty$ on a set of measure $0$ such that "$\infty \cdot 0 = 1$" (height times width). Hence, the integral of $\delta_0^2$ would be $\infty^2 \cdot 0 = \infty \cdot (\infty \cdot 0) = \infty \cdot 1 = \infty$. Again, this is very informal!